# UIStackView not centering arrangedview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

I am implementing a `UIStackView` and populating a `UIStackView` dynamically. But when there is a single view in `UIStackView`, the view is not centred in the `UIStackView`.

I use horizontal axis, center alignment and `fill equality` distribution in `UIStackView`. How can I start to populate `UIStackView` by putting views in center of the `UIStackView`?

Current behaviour of `UIStackView`

[image]

I want to start adding stars in the center of the `UIStackView`
[image]

I am new to `UIStackView` sorry for an easy question.

I'm adding arranged views like;

```
tmpView = [[UIView alloc] init];
tmpImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconStar"]];
[tmpView addSubview:tmpImageView];

[self.horizontalStackView addArrangedSubview:tmpView];
```

How can I achieve desired behaviour?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot. It's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: please share the scenario as its hard to understand what do u mean by center??

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure the stack view itself is taking up the whole horizontal space (anchor to left and right sides of the super view)?

Comment: I define a width constraint on UIStackView. I can not change background color of stackview thus I'm not sure actually. Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is as I thought. When you set the `alignment` of a `UIStackView` this works perpendicular to the `axis` of the stack view.

So in your case, the `center` means it will center the items from top-to-bottom (which it is doing).

In the direction of the `axis` the stack view will fill up from the top (in a `vertical` axis) or from the left (in a `horizontal` axis).

If you want your image to be centered like in your second screen shot then you could change the `axis` to `.vertical` and it would work. Without knowing what your end goal is I can't really recommend a specific solution.

If all you want is to align the single image this way then this should be fine.

Comment: Just like you said, I converted to vertical stackview. It worked for the first image but when I add the second image, it adds the second image below the first one. But I want to add it beside first one.

Comment: @TheZipper OK, so then it wouldn't be centered... explain what your end goal is. If you drip feed questions then you will get drip feed answers. Just explain the end goal. No where in your question do you mention multiple images.

Comment: @TheZipper try setting the `axis` to `horizontal` again but change the `distribution` to `equallyCentered`. I don't know what you're trying to achieve so no idea if this will work.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. I want to implement a horizontal container and add images to that container. I want images to start appearing in the center of container. When new image is added all images should be centered again and new image should appear beside of the previous one.

Comment: @TheZipper ok, so what happens if there are 100 images in it?

Comment: I will limit it to 5 so they will fit into container. Images wont be needed to resize.

Comment: @TheZipper ok then. Try what I said in the comment. Set the axis back to `horizontal` and change the `distribution` to `equallyCentered`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130960/discussion-between-thezipper-and-fogmeister).